# How to change a site background color using the browser's address bar?

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarklet, address-bar

When I type in the address bar in Google Chrome or any other browser:

```
javascript:alert("hello");​​​​​
```

It works, but

```
javascript:document.body.style.background="Red";
```

doesn't. Why is that? How to use the address bar to change the background color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `;void 0` after the bookmarklet. When the code has a non-`undefine` value, the page unloads, and the return value is printed.

A common way to write bookmarklets is:

```
javascript:(function(){ ... code ... })();
```

- The anonymous function returns `undefined`, so the page will not unload.
- The closure enables local variables, so that no conflicts can occur with existing global properties.

Note that in the latest versions of modern browsers (FF, Chrome), many objects are not available through the `javascript:`-URL in the **location bar**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate this ability in your Chrome configuration. It's turned off by default.

Comment: `alert` would not show anything when the bookmarklet-in-location-bar feature is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

XMLForDummies that's because of the fact that there is no access to document object from this place.